# Vertical oriented Metro WinJS ListView in Grouped Mode

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to implement a ListView with grouped items that renders like the WP7 LongListSelector shown below. I've tried adding a win-vertical class to the element with the data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" but since win-vertical seems to only apply to the viewport that didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of ListView Layout are you using? Using `ListLayout` instead of `GridLayout` does change the scroll direction from Horizontal to Vertical. But I don't see an easy way to add a group header for `ListLayout` list view. For `GridLayout`, there is a `groupHeaderPosition` property, but `ListLayout` object doesn't have this property. (Someone actually complained about the same thing.. at the end of this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx))So, you might need to hack around for the group names by adding a dummy "group name" item into your data source and sort it properly.

Ref:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211792.aspx

Comment: I'm using GridLayout since like you've mentioned the ListLayout has no support for Group Headers.